# Is Purim mentioned in later writings by Ezrah and his B"D?

Tags: tanach, purim, book-of-chronicles, ezra-nechemya

I'm trying to understand how the earlier generations saw Purim. Ezrah and his B"D wrote a series of books, such as Ezrah, Divrei Hayamim and more.

Is the Purim story or Meggilat Ester mentioned in them?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101386/759

Answer (score 3):

In Megillah 11a, R' Dimi bar Yitzchak says that a phrase in Ezra's prayer (9:9), ויט עלינו חסד לפני מלכי פרס, refers to the events of Purim.

Comment: On the same page other rabbis find hints to Esther in Mishlei, Kohelet, Yeshaya and more.

Comment: @DoubleAA True, but those obviously aren't contemporary, but prophetic. But why shouldn't we assume that Ezra would make reference to something that happened scarcely a decade earlier?

Comment: If it happened before he could be. There's just no indication from this line that it happened already. Besides why aren't you citing 4:6?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think that in a public prayer, Ezra is more likely to be referring to something specific that already happened. (The other examples from Tanach either aren't prayers, or - as in the example from Tehillim - are fairly generic.) And as for 4:6, that would be more relevant to the now-deleted comment thread on the OP about whether and how secular history fits with Tanach, but there's nothing in that verse that refers to Purim, just to Achashverosh.